# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_01409f5f7cae8788b3a2ccca28c521d8/client/package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm trying to do a production build on Heroku of a udemy course React project.  I've tried so many things to make it work but I'm completely at a loss.

The output from the Heroku build process:

> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Creating runtime environment
>
> ```
>    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>    NODE_ENV=production
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
>    NODE_VERBOSE=false
> ```
>
> -----> Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json):  12.17.0
>          engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.5
>
> ```
>    Resolving node version 12.17.0...
>    Downloading and installing node 12.17.0...
>    Bootstrapping npm 6.14.5 (replacing 6.14.4)...
>    npm 6.14.5 installed
> ```
>
> -----> Restoring cache
>          Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
>          Module installation may take longer for this build
>
> -----> Installing dependencies
>          Installing node modules (package.json)
>
> ```
>    > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_01409f5f7cae8788b3a2ccca28c521d8/node_modules/nodemon
>    > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
>
>    Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
>     > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
>
>    added 267 packages from 183 contributors and audited 268 packages in 11.725s
>
>    12 packages are looking for funding
>      run `npm fund` for details
>
>    found 0 vulnerabilities
> ```
>
> -----> Build
>          Running heroku-postbuild
>
> ```
>    > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_01409f5f7cae8788b3a2ccca28c521d8
>    > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
>
>    up to date in 0.618s
>    found 0 vulnerabilities
>     npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path /tmp/build_01409f5f7cae8788b3a2ccca28c521d8/client/package.json npm
> ```
>
> ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/tmp/build_01409f5f7cae8788b3a2ccca28c521d8/client/package.json' npm
>   ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
>   ERR! enoent  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm
>   ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.h4E00/_logs/2020-05-27T18_18_35_286Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 254 npm ERR! server@1.0.0
>   heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix
>   client && npm run build --prefix client` npm ERR! Exit status 254 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /tmp/npmcache.h4E00/_logs/2020-05-27T18_18_35_303Z-debug.log
>   -----> Build failed
>
> ```
>    We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>
>    If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>    https://help.heroku.com/
>
>    Love,
>    Heroku
>      !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
> ```

From the server index.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Express will serve production assets
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  // Express will serve index.html file if it doesn't recognise the route
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', "index.html"));
  });
}
```

The server package.json:

```
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.17.0",
        "npm": "6.14.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "server": "nodemon index.js",
        "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
        "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.15",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "passport": "^0.4.1",
        "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
        "stripe": "^8.55.0"
    }
}
```

.gitignore:

```
node_modules
dev.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that because I hadn't deleted the .git created by create-react-app in my /client directory, this was stopping the /server repository including the front-end files.  So just had to delete this and reinitialise the /server git repository.

Comment: I'm also running into this same issue. I did just as you said: delete the .git repository in my client directory and reinitialize my git repository in my server repository, but it didn't work for me. I'm trying to push a MERN build where the express server serves the ReactJS build folder.

Comment: having the same problem as @Joe

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete .git file that created by create-react-app
try this:
first in main app folder delete .git file watch out for hiden folders
then go to client and search for .git in there if there was any delete it
in terminal go to your project folder and type `git init`
then follow the steps that tells you on your heroku main dashboard page